# How to integrate indoorAtlas api for Indoor Mapping with IONIC 1 and angular 1?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How to integrate indoorAtlas api with IONIC 1 and angular 1? 
Here [Go to documents](http://docs.indooratlas.com/cordova/getting-started.html) They have shown integration with cordova app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the entire cordova code inside controller code of angularJS as shown below, and use in the front end as you want.

```
angular.module('IndoorMap', [])

.controller('IndoorMapCtrl', ['$scope','$translate', '$rootScope',
    function($scope, $translate, $rootScope) {

    $scope.startPositioning = function() {
            cordovaExample.startPositioning();
        };

        $scope.stopPositioning = function() {
            cordovaExample.stopPositioning();
        };

  var cordovaExample = {
            watchId: null,
            regionWatchId: null,
            marker: null,
            retina: window.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? true : false,

  // Starts positioning the user in the given floorplan area
            startPositioning: function() {
                SpinnerPlugin.activityStart('Move around to get a location');

                if (this.watchId != null) {
                    IndoorAtlas.clearWatch(this.watchId);
                }
                this.watchId = IndoorAtlas.watchPosition(this.showLocation, 
 this.IAServiceFailed);
                cordovaExample.startRegionWatch();
            },

    // Stops positioning the user
            stopPositioning: function() {
                IndoorAtlas.clearWatch(this.watchId);
                cordovaExample.stopRegionWatch();
                alert("IndoorAtlas positioning stopped");
            }


    .config(['$stateProvider', '$translateProvider', function($stateProvider, $translateProvider) {

    $stateProvider

        .state('indoorMap', {
        url: '/indoorMap',
        parent: 'menu',
        cache: false,
        views: {
            'appContent': {
                templateUrl: 'view/IndoorAtlasView/indoorAtlasMap.html',
                controller: 'IndoorMapCtrl'
            }
        },
    });

}]);
```